# Selected local files not displaying Shiny app with different criteria

Tags: r, shiny

I tried searching online a lot for a similar question but could not find one that helps with my case. I am very new to Shiny so I hope you all can help me out. Below is a form of the code I have.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(gridExtra)
library(png)
library(grid)

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Compare"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      pickerInput(inputId = "countyInput", label = "Filter county",
                  choices = c("County1", "County2", "County3", "County4", "County5"),
                  options = list(`actions-box` = TRUE,size = 10, `selected-text-format` = "count > 9"),
                  multiple = TRUE),
      checkboxGroupInput(inputId = "reasonInput", label = "Filter reason",
                         choices = c("reason1", "reason2", "reason3"))
    ),
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput("plot")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    filename <- normalizePath(file.path("<path>", paste0(input$countyInput, " ", input$reasonInput, ".png", sep = ""))) # you had one extra space before .png
    filename <- filename[file.exists(filename)]
    pngs = lapply(filename, readPNG)
    asGrobs = lapply(pngs, rasterGrob)
    p <- grid.arrange(grobs=asGrobs, nrow = 1)
    }, width = 1000)
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

In the UI you can see in the drop down menu I can select multiple counties and combo them with a reason. In my folder I have many png files titled in this generic format: "CountyX reasonY .png" (there is a space before the file extension).

In my actual case I know I have these files on my computer:

- County1 reason1
- County1 reason2
- County1 reason3
- County1 reason4
- County2 reason1
- County2 reason 4

However in Shiny when I select to display County1&2 and tick reason1&4 I only see

- County1 reason1
- County2 reason 4

instead of

- County1 reason1
- County1 reason 4
- County2 reason1
- County2 reason 4

even though I know that these files do exist (as I mentioned above).

I have uploaded some files for experimentation: [County1 reason1](https://master.tus.io/files/b8d318d0aab90654a68db1bb18f63670), [County1 reason2](https://master.tus.io/files/c192f15c4a2ccac15fc032d257025fa0), [County1 reason3](https://master.tus.io/files/39b6e50471e865caf7d0d7e37a5a3d65), [County1 reason4](https://master.tus.io/files/3a96f1a2ffdd1f8f16cee13141641208), [County2 reason1](https://master.tus.io/files/c438d333710413efd12b13f0243a3a6e), [County2 reason4](https://master.tus.io/files/5ae52753b43cfc6f27e4f4bebe801146)

This is the best I can describe my problem. Hope you can help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When writing a Shiny application, it is always good to follow reactive programming principles (by using `reactives()` often but this is not the only requirement) and to sanitize your input with `req()` (see [here](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/req.html)) as much as possible.

Your question about having the specific combination in file names is more related to R than Shiny. Using `paste()` with `lapply()` should be sufficient to achieve what you need. On the other hand, as a rule of thumb, you should never leave spaces in the file names, use a hyphen or underscore if needed.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Compare"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      pickerInput(inputId = "countyInput", label = "Filter county",
                  choices = c("County1", "County2", "County3", "County4", "County5"),
                  options = list(`actions-box` = TRUE,size = 10, `selected-text-format` = "count > 9"),
                  multiple = TRUE),
      checkboxGroupInput(inputId = "reasonInput", label = "Filter reason",
                         choices = c("Reason1", "Reason2", "Reason3"))
    ),
    mainPanel(
      uiOutput("images")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  file_name <- reactive({
    req(input$countyInput)
    req(input$reasonInput)
    paste0(unlist(lapply(input$countyInput, function(i) {
      paste0(i, input$reasonInput)
    })), ".png")
  })

 # creating multiple outputs:
  output$images <- renderUI({
    tagList(
      lapply(file_name(), function(file) {
        output[[paste("img", file, sep = "_")]] <- renderImage({

          filename <- file.path(Sys.getenv("HOME"), file)
          # validation intermed objects and msg displayed in UI:
          shiny::validate(
            shiny::need(file.exists(filename), "File not found.")
          )

          list(src = filename,
               alt = paste("Image name", file))
        }, deleteFile = FALSE) # we don't want Shiny to delete our file after read.
      })
    )
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Wow thanks for the answer. I tried running this and selecting some choice combinations, but it didn't work.. Sorry for being so late on this, but do you mind explaining in more detail how this code works because I am so new to Shiny that I am having trouble interpret this.. I have never seen a lot of these functions like `Sys.getnv()` `tagList()` `unlist()` `validate()` and how they work in this Shiny app

Comment: I tried running this and selecting some choice combinations, but it didn't work.. I think the file is not being properly located? It gives me error File not found: https://imgur.com/jkUwmuQ. Does `"HOME"` auto locate the environment (working directory) or what is the purpose of that/how does it work?

Comment: I've been only writing R at beginner level for undergraduate research for about a year and Shiny for about 2 weeks (both ~3hrs a week) so I'm trying to learn the best I can. Thanks for the help and the answer; it is very appreciated!

Comment: Yes, `Sys.getenv("HOME")` locates your home directory. Just change the directory specified in the `filename` with the path which your images stay.

Comment: Ok thanks. When I select some combinations, I get a blue question mark. Do you know how to fix this bug? I think I tried every solution I could find online..